# Changing a dataframe column type to int32

Tags: python, cython

I am trying to pass dataframe columns from Python to Cython:

Python code

```
evaluate_c(
        AnimalLogicPy(data[COL_ANIMAL_ID].values,              
        data[COL_ANIMAL_POWER].values,
        )
```

Cython code

```
cpdef void evaluate_c(
        int[:] animal_ids,
        int[:] animal_power,
        ):
```

where on the Python side `data[COL_ANIMAL_ID]` and `data[COL_ANIMAL_POWER]` have the type: int64

However I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'int' but got 'long'
```

I want to use `int` values in Cython. I've done some reading and I think its because the dataframe columns in question are of type `int64` which I think is becoming a long and should be `int32`.

I have tried on the Python side to change the type using:

```
data.astype({COL_ANIMAL_ID: 'int32'}).dtypes
data.astype({COL_ANIMAL_POWER: 'int32'}).dtypes
```

But I still get the ValueError.

How can I change the column type on the Python side from int64 to int32?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just convert it to a NumPy array with the correct `dtype`.

There are multiple ways of achieving this, the most direct of which is via the [`.to_numpy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html) method:

```
data[COL_ANIMAL_ID].to_numpy('int32')
```

---

To give you a minimal working example, let us assume we have the following Cython function (for simplicity compiled with IPython's Cython magic):

```
%%cython -c-O3 -c-march=native -a
#cython: language_level=3, boundscheck=False, wraparound=False, initializedcheck=False, cdivision=True, infer_types=True


cpdef int summer(int [:] data, int n):
    cdef int result = 0
    for i in range(n):
        result += data[i]
    return result
```

Then the following code works:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, (3, 4)))
print(df)
#     0   1   2   3
# 0  44  47  64  67
# 1  67   9  83  21
# 2  36  87  70  88


arr = np.array(df[0], dtype=np.int32)
print(summer(arr, arr.size))  # the array is fed to the Cython func
# 147

print(summer(df[0].values.astype(np.int32), df[0].size))  # directly from the Pandas's series
# 147

print(summer(df[0].to_numpy(dtype=np.int32), df[0].size))  # even more concisely
# 147

print(df[0].sum())  # checking that the result is correct
# 147
```